# Spark saveAsTable throws NoSuchTableException

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I'm using pyspark's (Spark 2.3.2) `saveAsTable` as follows:

```
df.write.format("parquet") \
  .sortBy("id") \
  .bucketBy(50, "some_column") \
  .option("path", "test_table.parquet") \
  .saveAsTable("test_table", mode="overwrite")
```

In the case where the table already exists (therefore mode "overwrite"), this leads to a `NoSuchTableException`:

```
org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.NoSuchTableException: Table or view 'test_table' not found in database 'test_database';
at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.catalog.SessionCatalog.requireTableExists(SessionCatalog.scala:184)
at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.catalog.SessionCatalog.listPartitionsByFilter(SessionCatalog.scala:927)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.CatalogFileIndex.filterPartitions(CatalogFileIndex.scala:73)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.CatalogFileIndex.listFiles(CatalogFileIndex.scala:59)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.FileSourceScanExec.org$apache$spark$sql$execution$FileSourceScanExec$$selectedPartitions$lzycompute(DataSourceScanExec.scala:189)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.FileSourceScanExec.org$apache$spark$sql$execution$FileSourceScanExec$$selectedPartitions(DataSourceScanExec.scala:186)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.FileSourceScanExec.inputRDD$lzycompute(DataSourceScanExec.scala:308)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.FileSourceScanExec.inputRDD(DataSourceScanExec.scala:295)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.FileSourceScanExec.inputRDDs(DataSourceScanExec.scala:315)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.WholeStageCodegenExec.doExecute(WholeStageCodegenExec.scala:605)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$execute$1.apply(SparkPlan.scala:131)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$execute$1.apply(SparkPlan.scala:127)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$executeQuery$1.apply(SparkPlan.scala:155)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:151)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.executeQuery(SparkPlan.scala:152)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.execute(SparkPlan.scala:127)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.columnar.InMemoryRelation.buildBuffers(InMemoryRelation.scala:107)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.columnar.InMemoryRelation.<init>(InMemoryRelation.scala:102)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.columnar.InMemoryRelation$.apply(InMemoryRelation.scala:43)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.CacheManager.org$apache$spark$sql$execution$CacheManager$$recacheByCondition(CacheManager.scala:145)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.CacheManager$$anonfun$recacheByPath$1.apply$mcV$sp(CacheManager.scala:201)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.CacheManager$$anonfun$recacheByPath$1.apply(CacheManager.scala:194)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.CacheManager$$anonfun$recacheByPath$1.apply(CacheManager.scala:194)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.CacheManager.writeLock(CacheManager.scala:67)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.CacheManager.recacheByPath(CacheManager.scala:194)
at org.apache.spark.sql.internal.CatalogImpl.refreshByPath(CatalogImpl.scala:508)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.InsertIntoHadoopFsRelationCommand.run(InsertIntoHadoopFsRelationCommand.scala:174)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource.writeAndRead(DataSource.scala:532)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.CreateDataSourceTableAsSelectCommand.saveDataIntoTable(createDataSourceTables.scala:216)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.CreateDataSourceTableAsSelectCommand.run(createDataSourceTables.scala:176)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.DataWritingCommandExec.sideEffectResult$lzycompute(commands.scala:104)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.DataWritingCommandExec.sideEffectResult(commands.scala:102)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.DataWritingCommandExec.doExecute(commands.scala:122)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$execute$1.apply(SparkPlan.scala:131)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$execute$1.apply(SparkPlan.scala:127)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$executeQuery$1.apply(SparkPlan.scala:155)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:151)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.executeQuery(SparkPlan.scala:152)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.execute(SparkPlan.scala:127)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.toRdd$lzycompute(QueryExecution.scala:80)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.toRdd(QueryExecution.scala:80)
at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter$$anonfun$runCommand$1.apply(DataFrameWriter.scala:656)
at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter$$anonfun$runCommand$1.apply(DataFrameWriter.scala:656)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withNewExecutionId(SQLExecution.scala:77)
at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.runCommand(DataFrameWriter.scala:656)
at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.createTable(DataFrameWriter.scala:458)
at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.saveAsTable(DataFrameWriter.scala:433)
at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.saveAsTable(DataFrameWriter.scala:393)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:244)
at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:357)
at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:282)
at py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:132)
at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)
at py4j.GatewayConnection.run(GatewayConnection.java:238)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

It looks like the existing table gets successfully [dropped](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/v2.3.2/sql/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/DataFrameWriter.scala#L432) but the [following attempt to create the new table](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/v2.3.2/sql/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/DataFrameWriter.scala#L433) seems to require the table to exist (see 2nd line of the stacktrace). Is this a bug or do I miss something?

Comment: I face a similar problem while overwriting parquet files. Will be following this thread.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be working fine in **Spark 2.4**, in a gist tried a create a sample dataframe and then have it written to Hive via spark.

```
from pyspark.sql import Row
l = [('Ankit',25),('Jalfaizy',22),('Magesh',20),('Bala',26)]
rdd = sc.parallelize(l)
people = rdd.map(lambda x: Row(name=x[0], age=int(x[1])))
schemaPeople = spark.createDataFrame(people)
schemaPeople.write.format("parquet").saveAsTable("test_table_spark", mode="overwrite")
```

After the successful write, checked to verify the Hive table and then modified the dataframe and did the same `saveAsTable` the data was overwritten with the new dataframe

```
l = [('Ankit',25),('Jalfaizy',22),('Suresh',20),('Bala',26)]
```

could you please try the same in your spark shell and see if it works out...

Retried to do the same into a External Hive Table

```
>>> schemaPeople.show()
+---+--------+
|age|    name|
+---+--------+
| 25|   Ankit|
| 22|Jalfaizy|
| 20|  Suresh|
| 26|    Bala|
+---+--------+

>>> spark.sql("SELECT * FROM EXT_Table_Test").show()
+---+--------+
|age|    name|
+---+--------+
| 25|   Ankit|
| 22|Jalfaizy|
| 20|  Magesh|
| 26|    Bala|
+---+--------+

>>> schemaPeople.write.format("parquet") \
...   .option("path", "hdfs://path/tables/EXT_Table_Test") \
...   .saveAsTable("test_table", mode="overwrite")
```

Reading the updated table again caused the following error

> Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: File does not exist:
>   hdfs:///tables/EXT_Table_Test/000000_0 It is possible the
>   underlying files have been updated. You can explicitly invalidate the
>   cache in Spark by running 'REFRESH TABLE tableName' command in SQL or
>   by recreating the Dataset/DataFrame involved.

```
>>> spark.sql("SELECT * FROM EXT_Table_Test").show()
```

After doing the **REFRESH TABLE**, the read from the Spark was successful, though before doing the refresh I was able to see the updated data in HIVE shell.

```
>>> spark.sql("REFRESH TABLE EXT_Table_Test")
DataFrame[]
>>> spark.sql("SELECT * FROM EXT_Table_Test").show()
+---+--------+
|age|    name|
+---+--------+
| 25|   Ankit|
| 22|Jalfaizy|
| 20|  Suresh|
| 26|    Bala|
+---+--------+
```

Comment: Hi @Joby, thanks for your input. Note that your answer does not consider external tables (`.option("path", "/some/folder/file.parquet")`) which I think is part of the issue. Also, writing a table if it does not previously exist is not a problem. There seems to be a problem if the table already exists, and, although it _does_ get dropped, there seems to be an issue with creating the new one.

Comment: @MartinStuder have updated the same for external tables, please do check if it helps in anyway

Answer (score 0):

In spark 2.4 create a table with overwrite fails. To resolve the issue set the below property.

Set the flag `spark.sql.legacy.allowCreatingManagedTableUsingNonemptyLocation` to true.

For pyspark use the following command:

```
spark.conf.set("spark.sql.legacy.allowCreatingManagedTableUsingNonemptyLocation","true")
```